# How do I consume a key event in javascript, so that it doesn't propagate?

Tags: javascript

How do I consume a key event in javascript, so that it doesn't propagate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and/or [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: assuming the question regards jQuery, wich wasn't specified.

Comment: @yoda: Those aren't jQuery methods, jQ just wraps the native ones. I agree that linking to jQ docs is slightly unfortunate.

Comment: stopPropagation didn't worked in my Xul app, but preventDefault did, thanks! :)

Comment: @Piskvor: true, it just wraps the native methods in browsers which support the native methods. In other browsers it sets returnValue = false and cancelBubble = true, so it does provide some simplification of the calling code. But since Tom is writing an xul app, I guess cross-browser concerns are not important.

Comment: In other part of the program stopPropagation worked, while preventDefault not. Interesting..

Comment: @Tom: Yes, they do subtly different things. The best place for Firefox/xulrunner documentation probably starts here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event

Comment: @Tom, @Douglas: `preventDefault()` has nothing to do with event propagation and `stopPropagation()` has nothing to with suppressing the native browser action. I'd say the difference is far from subtle.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't want the event to propagate and you're not using jQuery (or another library that wraps native browser events), you need to use the event's `stopPropagation()` method in most browsers and its `cancelBubble` property in IE. Don't bother with `return false` or `preventDefault()`: those only affect whether the native browser action happens for the event and have nothing to do with propagation.

For example:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (typeof evt.stopPropagation != "undefined") {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I like your explanation, but it didn't work; `preventDefault()` did work.

Comment: @daCoda: In which case, what you wanted was to prevent the default behaviour of the event rather than to stop even propagation.